# Lead vs Conduct

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I would like to express some secondary professional activity in not so strong / embellishing style.
Think, some knowledge/experience sharing inside the company, more informal rather than formal.

If I use 'Led xxx' it looks fine but a bit overhyped.

'Conducted xxx' seems to be ok, but natives don't use it at all; I see examples only from non-native speakers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only orchestras, research, investigations, talks and a few others are conducted in English. If you are a group leader or a company leader,  you are not conducting anything.

Comment: I am ready to change 'xxx' to any other 'xyz' - the wording doesn't matter; the verb does.

Comment: "Conduct training"

Comment: Again, conducted x for led x is a non-starter. I believe I said a few others. State your context and let;s no belabor the point. :)

Comment: "conduct experiment" , "conduct campaign"

Comment: The context: knowledge/experience sharing inside the company, more informal rather than formal.

Comment: "some knowledge/experience sharing inside the company, more informal rather than formal" is vague - instructed? guided? supported? assisted? facilitated? promoted? organized? steered? initiated?

Comment: Organized - probably yes. Guided - probably yes. Carried out.

Comment: head up knowledge and experience sharing inside the company: to head up is very used in business lingo.

Comment: Thanks, head up is great, but strong:)

Comment: Please spell out what you were in charge of so we can get a handle on it. Did you lead teams? Plan projects? Prepare onboarding? Led is not formal in the least. Also: Ran, forged, initiated, created, opened, introduced, merged, meshed, handled, brought, set, established, mentored, and ... *delivered*. Spearheaded or pioneered are good, but puffed up for the resume.

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't something to be in charge - that was more like a free will to share experience and knowledge. Introduced is probably the best option. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe "enabled"?

Answer (score 0):

There is the precising definition of **facilitate** which is used in this context:

> *facilitating* [noun]:
>
> ...
>
> [2] the act or process of leading or moderating a discussion, especially as a person trained to do so:
>
> - *His degree in social work, law practice, and counselling experience have been valuable in the facilitating of a support group for lawyers
>   with depression.*

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/facilitating)]

It's a jargon usage, so not especially formal.

Comment: Thanks, the word is ok, but it implies more involvement. Also, there is a special format / role about facilitation - but the question is about less formal actions.